# CSS: display: flex vs. display: block padding behaviour

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please take a look at https://jsbin.com/jodorazone/1/edit?html,css,output

If I set parent to `display: block`, only the `padding` of the children is taken into account. If set to `display: flex`, child is rendered along with `padding` inside the parent's `padding`.

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: box-sizing: border-box is the reason, check f23 console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `span` is an `inline` element by default and padding top/bottom will not affect the height. If you want to set padding, just set `span` `display: block`. Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced

```css
body {
  margin: unset;
}

button, div {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button span,
div span {
  /* if button, div is set to display: block, their (parent) padding isn't factored in */
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><span>div</span></div>
  <button><span>button</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

About `display: flex` behaviour:

> The display value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified
>   display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container
>   is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent.
>   (See CSS2.1§9.7 [CSS21] and CSS Display [CSS3-DISPLAY] for details on
>   this type of display value conversion.)

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers

Comment: to be more precise the issue is only with the top/bottom padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, I have updated the answer, do you have any reference about this issue?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced (The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box)

Comment: and it's not about `won't work` but will not affect the height as padding-top/bottom works fine (add a background and you will see the effect)

Comment: "The display value of a flex item is blockified" - this is the kind of justification I was looking for :)